# How to get data from last hour, last day and last month with one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm logging queries which have been sent to my API like this:

```
id  |  timestamp
----+---------------------
1   |  2015-01-19 18:01:47
2   |  2015-01-19 20:41:37
3   |  2015-01-20 14:15:06
4   |  2015-01-21 13:02:51
5   |  2015-01-23 05:02:12
```

Now, I need to know how much queries have been made in the last 60 minutes, 24 hours and 30 days and group it like that:

```
HOURLY | DAILY | MONTHLY
-------+-------+--------
0      | 1     | 5
```

Is this possible to do in one query?

**Edit:**

I've used the suggestions from here and played a bit with the logical things until it worked the way I want it to.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 HOUR) <= `TIMESTAMP` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HOURLY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 DAY) <= `TIMESTAMP` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DAILY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 MONTH) <= `TIMESTAMP` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MONTHLY
FROM `REQUESTS`;
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select sum(case when timestamp between now() - interval 1 hour and now() then 1 else 0) hourly,
       sum(case when timestamp between now() - interval 1 day and now() then 1 else 0) daily,
       sum(case when timestamp between now() - interval 1 month and now() then 1 else 0) monthly
from   your_table
```

edited...

Comment: Beat me to it. Far more efficient than using sub queries.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried it in SQL Fiddle and it didn't produce the expected results.

Comment: Actually this shouldn't work, because nothing should be greater than `now()` unless your table is recording the future.

Comment: edited, now reads `timestamp + interval` rather than `timestamp - interval`

Comment: That fixed the one issue, but now it doesn't protect against future dates. If OP has 01/24/2016 in there table, it is returned in this result set. Not being nit picky, just testing in SQL Fiddle trying to get the right one.

Comment: edited again, should not count any future events now

Answer (score 8):

```
select sum(timestamp >= now() - interval 1 hour) as hour,
       sum(timestamp >= now() - interval 1 day) as day,
       sum(timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month) as month
from your_table
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb328a/2)

Comment: I think your logic is backwards here. You want `timestamp >= now() - interval 1 hour`. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48502/9).

Answer (score 0):

Another neat trick you can use here is the `SUM()` function with just a boolean expression inside of it. When you do that, MySQL will effectively count the number of rows that meet the condition. So, by using something like:

```
SUM(timeCol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```

It will just count the number of rows that have a timestamp within the last hour. Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(timecol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS hourly,
  SUM(timeCol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS daily,
  SUM(timeCol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS monthly
FROM myTable;
```

It worked for me in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48502/13).

**EDIT**

The above solution doesn't work if your table *does* have future dates, so if you want to ensure that you're only getting values in the last hour, day, or month, that *do not* exceed the current time, just add a where clause:

```
SELECT SUM(timecol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS hourly,
  SUM(timeCol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS daily,
  SUM(timeCol >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS monthly
FROM myTable
WHERE timeCol <= NOW();
```

Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa6478/1), that has an invalid record to show that it works.